# Laravel - Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES error when opening app

Tags: json, encoding, laravel-7

[Error screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN6W3.png) 
Hi, I deploied my Laravel app on a *shared server*; I got this error when i try to open my website: `Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES - assumed 'JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)`.

- I think it's a PHP issue but there's ***7.3 php version*** on my server (I used *Laravel 7*).
- I tried to open my homepage without any *blade tag* but it return the same result  [exception throwed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKVDB.png).

So I turned to you. I need help.

Comment: Encountered the same issue, the PHP JSON extension must be activated (at https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php you can find the constant which is causing this issue, linked to this extension). So see with your provider if this extension can be activated.

Comment: How do you solve it? I have the same isuue

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my openSUSE box installing the php7-json package, which in turn asked me to uninstall php8, because it conflicted with it.

In case you're (like myself) using openSUSE you should run:

```
sudo zypper install php7-json
```

to install php7-json.

Installation requirements for Laravel 5.7 are documented [here](https://en.opensuse.org/Laravel) under openSUSE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved with the command:

```
sudo phpenmod json
```

Then I restarted the web server and PHP.

```
sudo system nginx restart

sudo system php7.4-fpm restart
```

**Note: I used Nginx. If you use other web server such as Apache use the command: sudo service apache2 restart. And if you use a php version other than 7.4 replace it with your version.**